# An Unfinished Rebus

Tags: rebus

The solution of these rebuses form into one phrase, A) + B) + C), but the final part is missing. What is the missing part?

A)

[image]

B)

[image]

C)

---

Note:

> you don't need to make a rebus to answer, just typing it is suffice.

Hint 1:

> I found that hexomino's solution to A) is more *mature* than my intended solution.

Hint 2:

> Add a little bit of motion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think C) is

> Y

A) could be

> Pokémon X (poke M on X)

B) is

> & (amp or sand)

So with the final part it should be

> Pokémon X&Y, the game.

Comment: Correct! This is my intended solution.

Comment: Yay! Was not expecting to be the first to solve this. Great rebus :)

Answer (score 8):

I think the answer is

> [image]

That is to say

> **S**pencer

A)

> **M**arks - the 'X' is drawn as if to indicate the location of a concealed object - *"X marks the spot"*. The finger is pointing at the M to highlight the word "marks" in that sentiment and the fact that we generally refer to the store *Marks & Spencer* as *M&S*.

B)

> **&** - which is called *ampersand*. The picture sounds this out - *amp or sand*.

C)

> **S**pencer - the missing part I have included. The picture is of Mike *Pence*. Note how we use the same pointing finger to highlight the 'S' in the informal moniker *M&S*.

Comment: +1 for the work you’ve done with the Spencer rebus but unfortunately, while the B) is correct the A) and C) is not my intended answer. Although, I feel a little embarrassed now because your solution to A) is more cooler and mature than mine. All that being said, I *feel* that my solution is to a certain degree more self-contained and traditionally rebus-ish? than yours. Still, I will def. accept this if there’s no better solution posted here.